# Updating a Value with 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to figure this out for two nights now and can't do it. I'm trying to update a value using three tables (person, person_pet, pet). The pet's parent should be the person who owns the pet. I'm trying to get a one-to-one match by using only the pet.id and person_pet.pet_id. person_pet is a relations table stating which pet belongs to which person. The closest answer I could find was here ([Update SQL by joining 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410010/update-sql-by-joining-3-tables)).

Here's my best shot:

```
UPDATE pet
SET parent = 
(SELECT person.id
FROM person, person_pet, pet
WHERE
person_pet.pet_id = pet.id);
```

Please help point me in the right direction, thanks!

Here are the exact tables that I've been using:

person

```
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | first_name | last_name | age  | dead | phone_number | salary | dob  |
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+--------------+--------+------+
|  0 | Zed        | Shaw      |   37 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL | NULL |
|  1 | Terry      | Berry     |   42 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL | NULL |
|  2 | Tyler      | Brown     |   25 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL | NULL |
|  3 | Frank      | Smith     |  100 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL | NULL |
```

pet

```
+----+----------+------------+------+------+------+--------+
| id | name     | breed      | age  | dead | dob  | parent |
+----+----------+------------+------+------+------+--------+
|  0 | Zeds Pet | Unicorn    | 1000 |    0 | NULL |   NULL |
|  1 | Zeds Pet | Robot      |    1 |    0 | NULL |   NULL |
|  2 | Murphy   | Yellow lab |    6 |    0 | NULL |   NULL |
+----+----------+------------+------+------+------+--------+
```

person_pet

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+
| person_id | pet_id | purchased_on |
+-----------+--------+--------------+
|         0 |      0 | 0000-00-00   |
|         0 |      1 | 0000-00-00   |
|         2 |      2 | 0000-00-00   |
|         4 |      3 | 0000-00-00   |
|         5 |      4 | 0000-00-00   |
|         6 |      5 | 0000-00-00   |
|         7 |      6 | 0000-00-00   |
|         5 |      7 | 0000-00-00   |
+-----------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: As I understood it, the junction or relations table only tells me the person_id and pet_id. The pet table contains a column for the parent.

Comment: Please share your table datails...

Comment: After reviewing my tables, I noticed an error with the set up of person_pet where there are too many rows. If a solution involves me fixing this mistake that's certainly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming person_pet has two columns: pet_id and person_id would the following query work for you?

```
UPDATE pet
SET parent = person_pet.person_id
FROM pet
INNER JOIN person_pet ON person_pet.pet_id = pet.id
WHERE COALESCE(pet.parent,-1) <> COALESCE(person_pet.person_id,-1)
```

Not sure you need to even know about the person table in this scenario.

Comment: I received the following error when trying to plug this in: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM pet
INNER JOIN person_pet ON person_pet.pet_id = pet.id
WHERE COALESCE(pet.' at line 3

Comment: Is there something I could do a better job explaining? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE pet
SET parent = 
(SELECT person.id
FROM person, person_pet, pet
WHERE
person_pet.pet_id = pet.id and person_pet.person_id=person.person_id);
```

Comment: This throws the following error when I try to plug it in: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'pet' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Is there something you need to know that I could do a better job explaining?